# Multiple images are generated in WP-content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

when I upload the images in WordPress using the dashboard. upload media.
But when I go into the wp-content>>media or using Cpanel that multiple images generated with the same name.
Now my question
[image: In that image generated the multiple images]
1.is when I delete these images it will any effect on my site or it will generate them again.
2.This issue affects my website speed?

Answer (score 0):

The images come from you theme's/plugin's settings. The reason this is done, is to speed up loading time of you website. The theme registers several dimension that it uses on the frontend. Instead of always showing the full image, which can be very large, the theme loads the smaller versions (e.g. 400x400 pixels) whenever it only needs a small presentation of the picture.

No need to always download very large images anymore. Removing the images will cause problems. WHat you can do, if you find that several of these dimensions are not used at all on the frontend, is deregister these formats, using

```
remove_image_size($name)
```

For that, you need the name of the image size that was added by the theme/plugin. You can use this function to get all image_size:

```
function _get_all_image_sizes() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $default_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    foreach ( $default_image_sizes as $size ) {
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'width' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_w" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'height' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_h" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'crop' ] = get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) ? get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) : false;
    }

    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) ) {
        $image_sizes = array_merge( $image_sizes, $_wp_additional_image_sizes );
    }

    return $image_sizes;
}
```